# What is the recomended way to connect spring boot application and google Cloud SQL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, spring-cloud-gcp

When I read [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine) I see that the recommended way is using cloud sql proxy:

> To connect securely to Cloud SQL from Google Kubernetes Engine using a
>   public IP address, you **must** use the Cloud SQL Proxy.

From other side when I read [spring documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_jdbc.html) I see following way to implement:

add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and specify properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name
spring.datasource.username
spring.datasource.password
```

I tried the spring way and it works but I am not sure if it is the recommended way beacuse of google documentation. Could you please clarify it?

### P.S.

Spring boot approach stopped to work when I switched from public ip to private ip on cloudSQL side and I have no idea how to recover it?

Comment: Is your application actually running in GKE?

Comment: @cricket_007 you are correct!

Comment: Okay, and what do you mean by "switched from public ip to private ip"? Where did you switch? Inside the application?

Comment: I mean this: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/01/10/0005/3037/338909/09/0e9d444921.jpg

Comment: @cricket_007 please see previous comment(above)

Comment: I see it. I don't know what "default" means in terms of your GKE cluster, but if it's recommended to use SQL proxy, what issues are you having?

Comment: @cricket_007 it is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

The `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql` is a great library and I recommend using it if your are building a spring application. It uses the [Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory), which uses the same mechanism as the Cloud SQL proxy to connect.

With regards to switching to public vs private IP - there are a number of [specific requirements to using private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#environment_requirements). For GKE, you need to make sure you are using a VPC-native cluster, and that you are in the same region and VPC as your instance.

Comment: Could you clarify how to choose between public IP vs private IP ?

Comment: Is it safety to use public IP together with Cloud SQL JDBC SOCKET FACTORY ?

Comment: Private IP requires you to connect from a resource that is connected to a [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/). Private IP has lower latency (because traffic stays local), but isn't always an option depending on your needs (region, resource type, etc). Generally, I recommend using private IP if it works with your design and you want improved network performance. Otherwise, use public IP.

Comment: Public IP via the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory is safe - it uses IAM credentials to create an ephemeral certificate on a 1 hour rotation that is used to authenticate and encrypt your data using TLS.

Comment: Is it possible to use private api together with  Cloud SQL JDBC SOCKET Factory ?

Comment: Sure - you can specify [`iptypes=`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#specifying-ip-types), but you still have to meet the same requirements as you would normally with private ip connections.

Comment: could you provide step by step instruction? Actually I don't see the way in spring cloud gcp library how to specify iptype. We don't provide URL at all. Spring generates URL based on properties we provided. Please take a look: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_jdbc.html

Comment: Could you answer, please?

Comment: It's part of the JDBC url. Here's the link to the Readme for the Cloud SQL JDBC SocketFactory: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#specifying-ip-types

Comment: One more time, I use **spring cloud sql** library which I linked in the  topic. **spring cloud sql** library uses **Cloud SQL JDBC SocketFactory**. I agree that if I use **Cloud SQL JDBC SocketFactory** directly I could follow your advice but I use  **spring cloud sql** library. Does it make sense?

Comment: Again, you can use the JDBC url to specify this. Spring allows you to configure your datasource just using a JDBC url if you want: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql